# JQuery toggleClass with 2 Classes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working with this code: (Updated)

```
   <script>
$(function(){
//Radio Item 1
$("#radio1").change(function() {

$("#defaultwrapper").addClass("background_color_selected");
$("#default_wrapper").removeClass("def_background_color");

});

//Radio Item 2
$("#radio2").change(function() {

$("#default_wrapper2").addClass("background_color_selected");
$("#default_wrapper2").removeClass("def_background_color");

});



});
</script>
```

My problem is that I need the background-color of the selected radio to change and it's not toggling right now

Comment: Have you had a look at the documentation? http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/. It clearly says: *"**className** One or more class names (separated by spaces) to be toggled for each element in the matched set."*. Or, if you don't want both classes to be added, call `toggleClass` twice, or omit the flag.

Comment: With a boolean value, that will just add or remove _both_ of them, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Update)
In jQuery no event is fired when radio is unselected. Try to create global handler:

```
$(function(){
    $("input[type=radio]").change(function() {
        $("input[type='radio']", $(this).parent().parent()).each(function() {
            $(this).parent()
                .toggleClass("background_color_selected", this.checked)
                .toggleClass("def_background_color", !this.checked);
        });
    });
});
```

For html:

```
<div>
    <div class="def_background_color"><input type="radio" id="radio1" name="aaa" /> One</div>
    <div class="def_background_color"><input type="radio" id="radio2" name="aaa" /> Two</div>
</div>
```

Working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/THrYJ/

Answer (score 2):

```
  $(function(){
        $("#myradio").change(function() {
    $("#wrapper").toggleClass("classOne", this.checked).toggleClass("classTwo", !this.checked)
        }).change();
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have `classOne` present at first (f.e. `<div class="classOne" id="test">Text</div>`) you can switch classes like this: `$("#test").toggleClass("classOne classTwo");`. This will remove the class `classOne` (because its present yet) and it will add the class `classTwo` (as its not present yet).

Answer (score 1):

Hi i had the same problem but this is what i have done in my project...

```
    <script>
    $(".rtPanhold01").addClass("rtPanhold02");
        $(".rtPanhold01").removeClass("rtPanhold01");
</script>
```